Dedicated queues, distributed locks and high availability service
I would need some advise concerning the "design" for a software/service/architecture. Here are the states and requirements (considering an item A):

Item A's price, stocks, etc.. events can be generated by several "producers" services
Events for Item A must be processed by only one "consumer" service instance (in order to avoid conflict). A consumer would be able to be handle N different Items

My idea:

have the producers services add/queue events to dedicate queues (1 queue per item) + publish that events for an Item is available
have the consumers services "lock" the targeted Item that it is processing (via distributed locks) and process the dedicated queue.

Is that a viable solution? Knowing that I need a decent throughput and high availability?
Thanks for your help.

In case of Kafka you can partition the data by any arbitrary header object. Kafka can guarantee that all messages that has the same header will be routed to the same partition on a given topic. Then you can have 1 consumer per partition. Or in other words each partition has its own consumer service.

@PeterCsala, let's say a new partition is created, how can I make one of the running consumer service know about this new partition and claim its processing?

That's where Kafka rebalancing can be helpful.

Consider a solution based on durable execution like temporal.io. You create an execution per business entity and send events to it directly by the business id. Then each entity can perform whatever processing is needed. All the routing, partitioning and locking is handled by the underlying system out of the box.
